# Java task creation in cloudsim

Tags: task, creation, cloudsim

I have developed Java applications and now I want to create the cloudlets so that I can execute my applications in cloudsim. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In cloudsim, you can execute any applications as cloudlets only. For this you will have to design the cloudlets in terms of lenth, size, and utilization models , that best defines your application. This will be more difficult depending on the complexity of your application.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. The applications that I have developed are very simple and are GUI Applications. So, want to know if I can execute such applications in cloudsim. Could you give me some example about how to create / design a cloudlet?

Answer (score 0):

In cloudsim,there's a class Cloudlet.You can create object of this class for creating cloudlets. You can pass cloudlet_id,number of PE, File size, Output size etc according to your GUI cloudlet.

```
Cloudlet cloudlet = new Cloudlet(id, length, pesNumber, fileSize, outputSize, utilizationModel, utilizationModel, utilizationModel);
```

Same is documented [here](http://www.cloudbus.org/cloudsim/doc/api/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/Cloudlet.html)